# Searching parent id in cloudant

Tags: couchdb, reduce, cloudant

I have a Cloudant DB with the following structure:

```
{id: 1, resource:”john doe”, manager: “john smith”, amount: 13}
{id: 2, resource:”mary doe”, manager: “john smith”, amount: 3}
{id: 3, resource:”john smith”, manager: “peter doe”, amount: 10}
```

I needed a query to return the sum of amount, so I've built a query with **emit(doc.manager, doc.amount)** which returns

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"john smith","value":16},
{"key":"peter doe","value":10}]}
```

It is working like a charm. However I need the manager ID along with Manager name. The result I am looking for is:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":{"john smith",3},"value":16},
{"key":{"peter doe",null},"value":10}]}
```

How should I build a map view to search the parent ID?

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want in one query. Assuming you have the following three documents in your database:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "resource": "john doe",
  "manager": "john smith",
  "amount": 13
}
```

--

```
{
  "_id": "2",
  "resource": "mary doe",
  "manager": "john smith",
  "amount": 3
}
```

--

```
{
  "_id": "3",
  "resource": "john smith",
  "manager": "peter doe",
  "amount": 10
}
```

The closest thing to what you want would be the following map function (which uses a compound key) and a `_sum` reduce:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.manager, doc._id], doc.amount);
}
```

This would give you the following results with `reduce=false`:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1","key":["john smith","1"],"value":13},
{"id":"2","key":["john smith","2"],"value":3},
{"id":"3","key":["peter doe","3"],"value":10}
]}
```

With `reduce=true` and `group_level=1`, you essentially get the same results as what you already have:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["john smith"],"value":16},
{"key":["peter doe"],"value":10}
]}
```

If you instead do `reduce=true` and `group=true` (exact grouping) then you get the following results:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["john smith","1"],"value":13},
{"key":["john smith","2"],"value":3},
{"key":["peter doe","3"],"value":10}
]}
```

Each unique combination of the `manager` and `_id` field is summed, which unfortunately doesn't give you what you want. To accomplish what you want to accomplish, I think your best but would be to sum up the values after querying the database.

Comment: I think your answer is great and gives the user exactly what they need. There seem to be a little misunderstanding about the ids: there are document IDs and manager ids. I'd assume each manager has a unique id, even if they have the same name. If manager id is present in the document, then you can still emit a compound key as you showed in the example and use the `_sum` reduce function - this would result in a correct behaviour, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could still use a compound key of `[doc.manager, doc.id]`, yes. However, I think you would still run into the same issue that I outlined above.